# when logging in and clicking on manage account, it redirects me to a different page , while previously it worked fine. [ASP.NET]

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

After signing in into a user and clicking on "Manage account" to edit the users' details it used to redirect me to _ManageNav.cshtml, but when I added roles, it now redirects me to Index.cshtml.
It happened after I edited in Program.cs this

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

to

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

here are some of my files,
_ManageNav.cshtml:

```
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@{
    var hasExternalLogins = (await SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).Any();
}
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link u/ManageNavPages.IndexNavClass(ViewContext)" id="profile" asp-page="./Index">Profile</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link u/ManageNavPages.ChangePasswordNavClass(ViewContext)" id="change-password" asp-page="./ChangePassword">Password</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link u/ManageNavPages.PersonalDataNavClass(ViewContext)" id="personal-data" asp-page="./PersonalData">Personal data</a></li>
    u/if (hasExternalLogins)
    {
        <li id="external-logins" class="nav-item"><a id="external-login" class="nav-link u/ManageNavPages.ExternalLoginsNavClass(ViewContext)" asp-page="./ExternalLogins">External logins</a></li>
    }
</ul>
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Profile";
    ViewData["ActivePage"] = ManageNavPages.Index;
    var hasExternalLogins = (await SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).Any();
}
<h3>@ViewData["Title"]</h3>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link @(ManageNavPages.IndexNavClass(ViewContext))" asp-page="./Index">Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link @(ManageNavPages.ChangePasswordNavClass(ViewContext))" asp-page="./ChangePassword">Password</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link @(ManageNavPages.PersonalDataNavClass(ViewContext))" asp-page="./PersonalData">Personal data</a>
                </li>
                u/if (hasExternalLogins)
                {
                    <li id="external-logins" class="nav-item">
                        <a id="external-login" class="nav-link @(ManageNavPages.ExternalLoginsNavClass(ViewContext))" asp-page="./ExternalLogins">External logins</a>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <form id="profile-form" method="post">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger" role="alert"></div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input asp-for="Username" class="form-control" placeholder="Please choose your username." disabled />
                    <label asp-for="Username" class="form-label"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input asp-for="Input.PhoneNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your phone number." />
                    <label asp-for="Input.PhoneNumber" class="form-label"></label>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.PhoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <button id="update-profile-button" type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
u/section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

Program.cs:

```
#nullable disable
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
namespace ExploreJordan.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Manage
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;

        public IndexModel(
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [TempData]
        public string StatusMessage { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }
        public class InputModel
        {
            [Phone]
            [Display(Name = "Phone number")]
            public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        }
        private async Task LoadAsync(IdentityUser user)
        {
            var userName = await _userManager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
            var phoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);
            Username = userName;
            Input = new InputModel
            {
                PhoneNumber = phoneNumber
            };
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
            }
            await LoadAsync(user);
            return Page();
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
            }
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                await LoadAsync(user);
                return Page();
            }
            var phoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);
            if (Input.PhoneNumber != phoneNumber)
            {
                var setPhoneResult = await _userManager.SetPhoneNumberAsync(user, Input.PhoneNumber);
                if (!setPhoneResult.Succeeded)
                {
                    StatusMessage = "Unexpected error when trying to set phone number.";
                    return RedirectToPage();
                }
            }
            await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
            StatusMessage = "Your profile has been updated";
            return RedirectToPage();
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
#nullable disable
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
namespace ExploreJordan.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Manage
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        public IndexModel(
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [TempData]
        public string StatusMessage { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }
        public class InputModel
        {
            [Phone]
            [Display(Name = "Phone number")]
            public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        }
        private async Task LoadAsync(IdentityUser user)
        {
            var userName = await _userManager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
            var phoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);
            Username = userName;
            Input = new InputModel
            {
                PhoneNumber = phoneNumber
            };
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
            }
            await LoadAsync(user);
            return Page();
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
            }
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                await LoadAsync(user);
                return Page();
            }
            var phoneNumber = await _userManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);
            if (Input.PhoneNumber != phoneNumber)
            {
                var setPhoneResult = await _userManager.SetPhoneNumberAsync(user, Input.PhoneNumber);
                if (!setPhoneResult.Succeeded)
                {
                    StatusMessage = "Unexpected error when trying to set phone number.";
                    return RedirectToPage();
                }
            }
            await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
            StatusMessage = "Your profile has been updated";
            return RedirectToPage();
        }
    }
}
```

_LoginPartial.cshtml:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="manage" class="nav-link" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Account</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <form id="logoutForm" class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Homepage", "Home", new { area = "" })">
            <button id="logout" type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link border-0">Logout</button>
        </form>
    </li>
}
else
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " id="register" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " id="login" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

Login.cshtml.cs:

```
#nullable disable
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
namespace ExploreJordan.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;
        public LoginModel(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, ILogger<LoginModel> logger)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }
        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }
        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
        [TempData]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        public class InputModel
        { 
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            public string Email { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string Password { get; set; }    
            [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
            public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
        }
        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
            }
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                 true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Page();
               }
            }
            return Page();}}}
```

I tried change the Index.cshtml to make it like _ManageNav.cshtml but there was no styling

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get the index page and no styling even after manually modified the page, is that you haven’t control the logic.

When adding service of `AddDefaultIdentity()`, it automatically adds the `AddDefaultUI()`, the _layout and UI get rendered. But when you add the service of `AddIdentity()`, no UI is set.

To solve this you can simply add the service in your program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultUI()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

[image]